# SQL Injection on md5()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, md5, sql-injection

I was wondering if this query is vulnerable.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE password = '".md5($_POST['password'])."'");
```

or

`mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('" . $username . "','" . md5($password) . ") or die(mysql_error());`

The $_POST['password'] is not filtered through mysql_real_escape_string or something like that but it has an md5().

Is there a way to bypass that or is that completely safe?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: `md5` is outdated long ago.

Comment: I know. I dont use that code, I just want to know because I found it on some old projects.

Comment: Unless `md5` gives you something like `' OR 1 = 1 --`, it is secure

Comment: This code is obsolete in every way imaginable.